# changing colorbox href

Tags: jquery, href, colorbox

I don't want to use the iframe setting for colorbox, instead I want to click a link within the colorbox and load in another file in place of the current one.

```
Login failed, please <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox({href:'/admin/login.php'}); return false;" class='tryagain'>try again</a>.
```

This is obviously an in-line example - a typical jquery solution would be fine, i.e.

$('a.class).colorbox({href:"../admin/login.php"});

In effect I want to "change href of this (currently showing) colorbox". I want this new page to load within the existing colorbox.

Many thanks

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?:

```
<a class='tryagain' href="../url1.html">link1</a>
 <br/><br/>
<a class='tryagain' href="../url2.html">link2</a>
```

and

```
$(".tryagain").colorbox({
    width: "80%",
    height: "80%",
    iframe: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, problem is that this redirects to the the new location as a normal link would -- I want this new page to load within the existing colorbox.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, you would like to "mix" inline and iframe Colorbox usage so that once a user clicks on a on a given link, a content would appear in a Colorbox - and inside it, there would be another link, which would update the currently opened Colorbox instance with the new content.

**This could easily be done with binding Colorbox on a link which is inside the inline - likely hidden - HTML content which you would like to display in the Colorbox first.**

So I created a working demo example to you (and combined with some other stuffs like mixing Colorbox with Tooltip plugin), and uploaded it to **`jsfiddle.net`**:
http://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/aHcLx/

Here you can try it out right away if it fits your needs!
I hope that's what you asked for.